# TextField - enable button after leading whitespace

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield, whitespace

I have a `_saveButton` for the `_textField`, and I want the `_saveButton` to be enabled after a leading whitespace in the `_textField`.

I've tried various codes but this is the closest I got:

`- (IBAction)textFieldEditing` is connected to `_textField`'s `Editing Changed` event.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldEditing:(id)sender {

     if ([_textField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [_nameField.text hasPrefix:@" "]) {
         [_saveButton setEnabled:NO];
     }
     else {
      [_saveButton setEnabled:YES];
     }
}
```

This disables the `_saveButton` when `_textField` is empty or if it's prefixed with a space. But the user will have to clear back to the beginning, then enter text to have the `_saveButton` enabled. I want the `_saveButton` to be enabled as soon as the user enters character after the leading space, since I've already implemented to trim leading whitespace and trailing whitespace in the `- (IBAction)saveAction`, I don't mind user saving with whitespace.

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender {

     if (![_textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

         NSString *trimmedString = [_nameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

         _saveString = trimmedString;
     }
     else {
     }
 }
```

I hope everyone understand my question. What code am I missing? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `textFieldEditing:` to trim whitespace and see if the resulting string has any length:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *trimmedString = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    _saveButton.enabled = trimmedString.length > 0;
}
```

This code will disable the button as long as there is just whitespace. Once the user enters any non-whitespace characters, the button will be enabled.

Comment: Just a quick question. Do you know the difference between `whitespaceCharacterSet` and `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`??

Comment: See the docs for them. One includes new lines and one doesn't.